# How can I show the time left until progress bar is finished loading?

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar

I have one HTML5 progress bar with start value of 100. When clicked the button, its value will be reduced to 0 in 15 seconds. I have modified the code from example found in the internet. It is now in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8ycL/1/). It's now showing percent of the progress bar but I want it to show the time left until it finished loading. How can I do that ?

JS

```
$('#btnUpload').click(function() {
var time = 150; //15 secs
var bar = document.getElementById('progBar'),
    fallback = document.getElementById('downloadProgress'),
    loaded = 100;

var load = function() {
    loaded --;
    bar.value = loaded;

    /* The below will be visible if the progress tag is not supported */
    $(fallback).empty().append("HTML5 progress tag not supported: ");
    $('#progUpdate').empty().append(loaded + "% loaded");

    if (loaded <0) {
        clearInterval(beginLoad);
        $('#progUpdate').empty().append("Upload Complete");
        console.log('Load was performed.');
    }
};

var beginLoad = setInterval(function() {
    load();
}, time);

});
```

Comment: If the total time the operation will take is not known in advance, you cannot show time remaining unless you continually guess on the total time based on how much has completed so far in how much time which is what most uploaders do.

Comment: Sorry. It will be exactly finished in 15 secs. It's purposed for showing only. It has nothing to do with upload, it's just a label from the old example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "It will be exactly finished in 15 secs." then [is it what you wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/A8ycL/5/)?
Just put

```
var t = time-(time/100)*(100-loaded);
$('#progUpdate').empty().append(Math.round(t/10) + " sec left");
```

instead

```
$('#progUpdate').empty().append(loaded + "% loaded");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append the number of seconds onto your % loaded.

```
$('#btnUpload').click(function() {
    var time = 150; //15 secs
    var bar = document.getElementById('progBar'),
        fallback = document.getElementById('downloadProgress'),
        loaded = 100,
        totalTime = 15000;

    var load = function() {
        loaded --;
        totalTime -= time;
        bar.value = loaded;

        /* The below will be visible if the progress tag is not supported */
        $(fallback).empty().append("HTML5 progress tag not supported: ");
        $('#progUpdate').empty().append(loaded + "% loaded. " + Math.ceil(totalTime/1000) + " seconds remaining");

        if (loaded <0) {
            clearInterval(beginLoad);
            $('#progUpdate').empty().append("Upload Complete");
            console.log('Load was performed.');
        }
    };

    var beginLoad = setInterval(function() {
        load();
    }, time);

});
```